# Jquery datepicker not assigning date

Tags: jquery

I have a text box with an id of InactiveDate. It has a datepicker attached to it,

I tried the following but wasn't able to successfully populate the date:
(Note I hardcoded for testing)

```
$('#InactiveDate').datepicker('09/09/2012');
```

Although my control is called InactiveDate, looks like below it make is hidden so not sure what to try.

When I run above code no date gets populated.

Here is what it looks like:

```
    <div id="datePicker_InactiveDate">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <input id="InactiveDate" class="data" type="hidden" value="" name="InactiveDate">
    <input id="dp1342109969094" class="date hasDatepicker" type="text"     onchange="javascript:updateData_InactiveDate()" value="">
    </div>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="InactiveDate"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if it works for you............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this first:

```
var myDate = new Date('09/09/2012');
```

Now, call datepicker.setDate() and you're done:

```
$('#InactiveDate').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
```

Answer (score 5):

That's not how `.datepicker` works.  You need to use the `setDate` method.

```
$('#InactiveDate').datepicker('setDate', '09/09/2012');
```

Docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker (Click the "methods" tab)

Answer (score 1):

try out

```
var myDate = new Date();
var todaydate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
        myDate.getFullYear();
$("#InactiveDate").val(todaydate);
```

or

```
$('#InactiveDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

No need to apply format, it uses the datepicker defined.